# how to update xml file attribute with new value (add date time) in shell script?

Tags: xml, bash, shell, awk, sed

This is my xml below

```
<Deployer exitOnError="true" sourceType="Repository">
<Projects projectPrefix="">
<SubProject description="" name="Ship" overwrite="false" type="Repository">
</SubProject>
</Projects>
</Deployer>
```

I want o change name="Ship" to name="Ship"+currentdatetime using shell script. Any help appreciated.

I want to use sed or awk preferably (I dont want xmlstarlet as I cannot have xml tool box on my linux machine)

Please find below, which I tried.

```
sed "/DeployerSpec>/,<Project description='' name='bstar' overwrite='false' type='Repository'>" file

sed -i 's:<DeployerSpec exitOnError="true" sourceType="Repository"><Projects projectPrefix=""><Project description="" name="bstar" overwrite="false" type="Repository"></Project></Projects></DeployerSpec>:<DeployerSpec exitOnError="true" sourceType="Repository"><Projects projectPrefix=""><Project description="" name="bstar"+$(date+%x_%r) overwrite="false" type="Repository"></Project></Projects></DeployerSpec>:' sample.xml

sed -i.bak "s/<Project description='' name='bstar' overwrite='false' type='Repository'>/<Project description='' name='bstar'+$(date +%x_%r) overwrite='false' type='Repository'>/g" a.xml
```

Comment: *I cannot have xml tool box on my linux* - but you can easily install them as they are a PROPER tools for xml data manipulating

Comment: well my client doesn't approve that, my manager insists on fixing this with shell scripting alone !

Comment: `my manager insists on fixing this with shell scripting alone` then write one and ask if you get stuck...

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given your posted sample input plus what you have tried so far.

Comment: Included the scripts which I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
DATE=$(date)
sed 's/Ship/& '"${DATE}"'/g' Input_file
```

creating a variable named DATE which has current date, then simply using sed to substitute string Ship with Ship and current date.

Answer (score 3):

Struggling with managers and client is an eternal process ... I understand.
For you simple case you may use ***sed*** approach:

```
sed -i 's/name="Ship"/name="'"$(date)"'"/g' your.xml
```

The xml file content (you'll have a different datetime at your locale):

```
<Deployer exitOnError="true" sourceType="Repository">
<Projects projectPrefix="">
<SubProject description="" name="Mon 22 May 15:41:23 EEST 2017" overwrite="false" type="Repository">
</SubProject>
</Projects>
</Deployer>
```

---

- `-i` - to modify the file in-place
- `$(date)` - to get current datetime value

---

Anyway, if there would be more complex and sophisticated tasks like "change attribute `name` value if it's a child of the parent element `ServiceProject` and that parent should also have a child element `city` with attribute `balance` greater than `1000`". Unix shell tools will fail in such cases and your managers would have a need to reconsider their attitude for XML parsers

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo sed -i '/<Project\s\description=""/s/name="[^"]*/name="'"$(date)"'"/g' Demo.xml
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  And fix the errors before suggesting the use of `sudo`!